# React-Redux / Redux: Updating store from external function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

So I'm trying to update the store, and my component from a separate JavaScript file but I'm struggling a little bit.

The function I'm calling works in the component, but not from the file I'd like it to.  It kind of makes sense, and I think I'm close, I'd just like a bit of help getting this over the line!

Here's the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/reactredux-o5wbq

If you open `page.js` you'll see a Page component, that has two buttons with onClick functions.  When clicked, the value of the h1 changes - This works as expected.

Now if you open `newfile.jsx` (included in `index.js`)  I've set a timeout of 2.5 seconds that calls the success function in `actions.js`.  The function runs successfully as it logs "SUCCESS".  But as far as I can tell, the store doesn't update nor does the h1 text on the page.

Like I said, I think, at least I hope, I'm close.  But I'm really stuck as to where I need to go from here.  Any help would be really appreciated.  Thank you!

**Code:**
*The below is what doesn't seem to be working correctly*

```
import { successAction, errorAction } from "./actions";

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("Timeout Complete");
  successAction();
}, 2500);
```

I do have the following in my actual component, and I think that may be what I'm missing.  I just don't know how to format it in a way that will work in `newfile.jsx`.  As far as I can tell, it's sort of built into the way the component is being exported.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  status: state.status
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  successAction: () => dispatch(successAction()),
  errorAction: () => dispatch(errorAction())
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Page);
```

I've tried adding the below to `newfile.jsx`, but that didn't seem to work.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  status: state.status
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  successAction: () => dispatch(successAction()),
  errorAction: () => dispatch(errorAction())
});

connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
);
```

Comment: Just put the relevant code.  Please see [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import store in your `newFile.jsx`, and dispatch from there.

```
import { successAction, errorAction } from "./actions";
import store from "./store";

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("Timeout Complete");
  store.dispatch( successAction() );
}, 2500);
```

Comment: That was much easier than I thought it was going to be.  Thank you!

Comment: I have a question, if it's not too much to ask.  It should be an easy one, and it sounds pretty obvious.  Everywhere I want to update the store, I need to import it into that specific file?

Like, if I have file1.js, that gets imported into file2.js, which also has the store imported.  It still needs to go into both?

Comment: @nick yes you do.